# What does the phrase “Go Tiger!” mean?

Tags: american-english

I am learning the Java struts 2 by reading a book titled "struts 2 in action" and I encountered the phrase "Go Tiger!". I can't figure out what it means; can anybody give me the answer?

> If you have the pleasure of using Java 5 or higher, we highly recommend using generics to type your collections and maps. Besides being a recommended best practice, the Struts 2 type conversion mechanism can use generics-based typing to learn the correct target type for the conversions. If you do this, you don't have to use the properties file configuration. This is a big bonus for Java 5 users. Go Tiger!

Comment: Can you give us some more context?

Comment: @nohat: it's probably this note: "If you have the pleasure of using Java 5 or higher, we highly recommend using generics to type your collections and maps. Besides being a recommended best practice, the Struts 2 type conversion mechanism can use generics-based typing to learn the correct target type for the conversions. If you do this, you don't have to use the properties file configuration. This is a big bonus for Java 5 users. Go Tiger!"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

“Tiger” is the code name for Java 5. Thanks to the additional context from RegDwight, we can see that “Go Tiger!” is an exclamation saying something along the lines of “Hooray for Tiger! (because we get this bonus from it)”. “Go ___!” is a common exclamation intended to express approval and encouragement to a team or an individual.

Comment: Whether intentional or not, there is also a hint of sexual innuendo in the UK as Tiger is a common nickname used for sexually active people.  For instance, on hearing of a friend's sexual conquests, then you might exclaim, with a hint of sarcasm, "Go Tiger!".